# How to get the optimal weight using Lagrange multiplier in weighted averaging used in ensemble learning?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier

In the Generalized Ensemble Method section of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2438296_When_Networks_Disagree_Ensemble_Methods_for_Hybrid_Neural_Networks), the authors gave an optimization problem, which is

\begin{equation}
\min \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_i\alpha_jC_{ij} \\
\text{s.t.}\quad \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i=1 \\
\end{equation}
By using Lagrange multiplier and setting derivatives to zero, we get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^N\alpha_jC_{ij}=\lambda,~~~i=1,2,\dots,N \\
\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i=1 
\end{equation}

Now my question is how to manipulate the above equations and get the solution $\alpha_{i}=\frac{\sum_{j} C_{i j}^{-1}}{\sum_{k} \sum_{j} C_{k j}^{-1}}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling $\mathcal{1}= (1,\cdots, 1)$ the Lagrangian can be stated as

$$
L = \alpha^{\dagger}\cdot C\cdot \alpha + \lambda (\alpha\cdot \mathcal{1}-1)
$$

and the stationary points are the solution to

$$
\nabla L = 2 C\cdot \alpha + \mathcal{1}\lambda = 0
$$

now assuming $C$ invertible

$$
\alpha^* = -\frac 12 C^{-1}\cdot \mathcal{1}\lambda
$$

but

$$
(\alpha^*)^{\dagger}\cdot  \mathcal{1} = 1 = -\frac 12\lambda \mathcal{1}^{\dagger}\cdot C^{-1}\cdot  \mathcal{1}
$$

then

$$
\lambda^* = -\left(\frac 12\mathcal{1}^{\dagger}\cdot C^{-1}\cdot  \mathcal{1}\right)^{-1}
$$

and finally

$$
\alpha^* = \frac{C^{-1}\cdot \mathcal{1}}{\mathcal{1}^{\dagger}\cdot C^{-1}\cdot  \mathcal{1}}
$$